# Bootstrap - displaying user information -table? row?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to show basic user information using Bootstrap 3.0.2.:

First column:
First name
Last name
Phone

Second:
Mike Smith 123-1234

Third: "Edit" beside each field
(Sorry, having a hard time explaining with this editor).

I don't think a table is the right way to go. But, if use bootstrap Rows the rows are so tall it looks terrible. Has anyone does this before or has an example of something similar.

I ultimately want to copy the way your Amazon.com account looks if you want to edit your name, phone etc...

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of amazon's edit screen so that I know what to refer to?